NFSv3 / NFSv4 TCP ports
In short, I need to know if an NFSv4 share in my Ubuntu server 22.04 can work as NFSv3 with only port TCP 2049.
Let me give you the context:

I have a Ubuntu server 22.04 with PXE/iPXE environment, which involves TFTP, HTTP, SMB and NFS servers, all of them installed in the same Ubuntu server host.
I usually use this PXE server, and the systems using NFS are working ok with NFSv3 shares
Now I'm trying to develop a portable PXE server, an OpenWRT router, which SSH tunnels back home when I'm away from home. Then, for example, I redirect my router's port 445 for SMB to my Ubuntu server at home in port 445 too. HTTP uses tunnels too. But NFSv3 requires some TCP and UDP tunnels, which is more difficult to set up and also it's not very clear for me what exact tunnels I will need.
In this context, I read yesterday that NFSv4 only uses TCP 2049. Then I thought that if I set a NFSv4 share instead of NFSv3 for PXE, I could use that share at home and in remote networks too, with the router ssh tunneling to home with port TCP 2049. The thing is that, from what I googled and read, pxelinux is not easily compatible with NFSv4.
I also read that an NFSv4 can be defined, and later a client can request to mount that NFS share, and the client and the server will negotiate the highest NFS version available for the client and the server at the same time.

Now, my questions are:

If I set the NFSv4 at home (all ports open), and the pxelinux system tries to mount it, will it work as NFSv3?
And, Will it use just port TCP 2049, because the share was defined as NFSv4? or it will use NFSv3 common ports?
Then, finally, will I be able to tunnel TCP 2049 to home, and boot pxelinux systems with NFS only using TCP 2049?

I'd like to try myself, and tried to set up NFSv4, but I'm encountering problems with NFSv4 so I'd like to know this before investing more time.
